# FormData's types - TypeScript 3.5

Tags: typescript

Using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData):

```js
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('document_title', this.document.document_title)
formData.append('file', this.document.file)
formData.append('document_language', this.document.document_language)
```

Document interface:

```js
export interface IDocument {
  document_title: string
  file: File | null
  document_language: number
}
```

The error comes, when I try to `formData.append` not a `String` or `blob`, I'm getting an error:

> Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.Vetur(2345)

and same with a file being `null`. I guess a `FormData` has its own interface in TS that accepts only string or blobs? How can I override this behavior?

Do not write about `JSON.stringify()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using `as any` type assertion for compiler:

```
formData.append('document_title', this.document.document_title)
formData.append('file', this.document.file as any)
formData.append('document_language', this.document.document_language as any)
```

`JSON.stringify()` my number data feels wrong for me. On backend i transform formdata strings to intended types to store in db.

Comment: Not really solved, just turned off typechecking for those lines

Answer (score 0):

This is an interface for FormData body

```
export interface PostFileFormDataBody{
  [key: string]: string | Blob;
}
```